# php - Detect if i by itself is lower case and change it to upper

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to determine if an ' i ' by itself meaning there is a space on either side of it is lowercase and change that i to a capital I.

So far I have

```
$explode = str_replace(ctype_lower(' i '),' I ',$explode);
```

which is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `ctype_lower()` it will just replace the lower 'i' if it get's found in the string, just do this:

```
$explode = str_replace(' i ',' I ',$explode);
```

Comment: That was the first thing I had tried and it does not work, I just tried it again and still no go.

Comment: @CesarBielich Show us your input string!

Comment: ok I was wrong, it does work. I had something else after it that was making it lowercase again lol thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I think a `preg_replace` would suite this better that way you can use word bounds so it will match instances like `i'm`.  I'm assuming your are using this to correct miss typed instances of `I`.

```
$explode = preg_replace("/\bi\b/", "I", $explode);
```